# ¿Como puedo actualizar un registro en una base de datos sin usar una sentencia sql con phalcon

Tags: phalcon

Buen día

tengo la siguiente función.

```
/* Función para incrementar el contador para consecutivo de clientes*/
public function putAddConsecutiveClient($noCarteraSap)
{
    $model_get = new $this->modelClass;
    $model = $model_get::findFirst([
        "conditions" => ":noCarteraSap: BETWEEN desde AND hasta",
        "bind"       => ["noCarteraSap" => $noCarteraSap]
    ]);
    $model->contador = $model->contador + 1;

}
```

hasta donde tengo ya hace lo que quiero pero como puedo hacer que se actualice el registro en la base de datos sin usar una sentencia sql?

¿Es posible?

Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta es sí, puedes hacerlo mediante el método `save` de la clase [Model](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.4/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model) de Phalcon.

De todos modos comentarte que ésto no es más que una abstracción, evidentemente dentro utilizará sentencias para cualquier operación CRUD (más o menos optimizadas) y que para utilizar los métodos del ORM de Phalcon deberías extender tus clases de la clase `Model` + seguir la documentación.

Comment: Muchas gracias investigare sobre esto... Saludos

Comment: Si te sirve no te olvides de marcar mi respuesta como correcta, gracias!